# ERROR: zLog must be specified at creation time

Tags: znapzend

I have a question, i simply want to make a lokal backup of my zfs filesystem.
This is the command i got:
`znapzendzetup create --recursive --tsformat='%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S' SRC data DST '1y=>1w' HDD`

Now i always get the errormessage:
`zLog must be specified at creation time!`

What do i have to do, that it works? What could be my mistake?
Thank you in advance for the help